# MySQL: Count rows with consecutive dates leading up to given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that records shifts worked by employees. It's pretty simple, consisting of (reduced for simplicity): an auto-increment `primary key`, `employee_id`, `job_id`, `date`

A row is created for each shift worked, so if a particular employee doesn't work on a particular day, there will be no row for that employee for that date.

For a given day, I need to be able to return the number of consecutive days worked by each employee leading up to that day.

I have no idea where to start and would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Are you interfacing with a language like PHP or do you need a pure SQL answer?

Comment: You can use simple date arithmetic to find out all employees who either did or did not work all days in between two dates, but reporting the actual nr of consecutive days worked per employee will be a little more tricky, depending on exactly what you mean with "consecutive", how you treat weekends, hollidays etcetera.

Comment: Hi. Just to clarify a couple of points... yes, I am using PHP. I'd prefer a pure SQL solution (I'm pretty sure I could figure this out in PHP). Ronnis - employees may work on weekends, so all days are treated equal. Holidays are stored in a separate table, so if an employee has a holiday there won't be a record for that day (which is correct for my purposes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had a sequence of numbers, then the difference between those numbers and a sequence of dates will be constant.  We can use this fact to group the working days into groups with a minimum and maximum date:

```
select employee_id, min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
from (select s.*, date_sub(date, interval seqnum days) as grp
      from (select s.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
            from shifts s cross join
                 (select @rn := 0) const
           ) s
     ) s
group by employee_id, grp;
```

Once we have this, getting the length of time up to a particular date for a particular employee is pretty easy:

```
select employee_id,
       coalesce(datediff(XXX, 1+min(case when XXX between mindate and maxdate then mindate end)),
                0) as SequentialWorkingDays
from (select employee_id, min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
      from (select s.*, date_sub(date, interval seqnum days) as grp
            from (select s.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
                  from shifts s cross join
                       (select @rn := 0) const
                 ) s
           ) s
      group by employee_id, grp
     ) s
group by employee_id;
```

Comment: I'm going to see if I can get my head around this and run it on some test data. At first glance it's completely over my head, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Okay. First things first... THANKYOU! That's brilliant -- it works perfectly. I don't claim to understand how it works, but I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table name is `shift`, then the following query would provide you with the number of rows between the provided date and current date.

```
SELECT COUNT(`date`) AS working_days 
FROM `shift` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-01-02' AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't count the number of consecutive days worked, just the number of days. For example, if somebody doesn't work on the Thursday before a given Sunday, the consecutive count should be 2 (or 3 if they work on the Sunday), regardless of whether they've worked every other day for the last 100 years.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to count the instances if shifts by row number of the sorted employee id and dates, I think it would look something like:

```
SELECT employee_id, job_id, date, days_worked = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, CAST(date) ORDER BY date)
FROM shifts
```